# $||I_2|| \neq \sqrt{tr(I_2^T*I_2)}$

Tags: linear-algebra

$I_2 = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix} \Rightarrow tr(I_2) = 1 + 1 = 2 \Rightarrow ||I_2|| = \sqrt{tr(I_2^T*I_2)} = \sqrt{tr(I_2)} = \sqrt{2}$, but $||I_n||$ should be $1$.
What am i missing?

Comment: $\|A\|_2=\sqrt{\rho(A^TA)}$ where $\rho$ is the operator returning the largest magnitude eigenvalue of its input.

Comment: See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm) for the definition of matrix norm.

Comment: @Daryl: jeez, I looked at that article but I was focused on the "Frobenius norm" section. There it doesn't mention the $\rho$ operator. But now I see in the "Induced norm" section $\|A\|_2=\sqrt{\rho(A^TA)}$. Why is that?

Comment: The Frobenius norm and the 2-norm are different methods of finding a matrix norm. Induced norms are based on the underlying vector norms.

Comment: @Daryl: See my QR decomposition comment below. So when they say that $||Q|| = 1$ they are calculating $||Q||$ as $\sqrt{\rho(Q^TQ)}$ instead of $\sqrt{tr(Q^T*Q)}$?

Comment: Yes. This is because Q is an orthonormal matrix under the 2-norm by its construction. Since $Q^TQ=I$ and $\rho(I)=1$, the result follows. With your norm $\operatorname{tr}(Q^TQ)=m$, for $Q\in M^{m\times n}$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, $I'_2*I_2=I'_2,$ and since you haven't defined $M'$ we can't tell why $I'_2$ should be $I_2$.

What's the general theorem, not the specific case here?

EDIT: If $I'_2$ is the transpose, and $||I_2||$ is the determinant, you've found a contradiction. So either you missed something about how it was said, or whoever said that was true is wrong.

Comment: I'm not understanding. $I_2$ is the 2 × 2 identity matrix. The transpose of the identity matrix is the identity matrix.

Comment: There are different notations for the transpose.

Comment: That's what I thought. I'm going to edit the question.

Comment: Come on... $||A||$ means matrix norm

Answer (score 0):

Nothing. Why do you think it should be one? Analogy: let $I := [0,1]$, and $||.||$ be the usual Euclidian norm. Then $||I|| = 1$, but $||I \times I|| = \sqrt{2}$.

*Edit*( (I missed the index $n$ in the question): to make the matrix norm of $Id_n$ $1$ in all dimensions, you would need to apply some supremum norm, just as would need to in Euclidian space, to make the norm of the multi-dimensional unit cube $I^n$ 1. If you define it as this trace norm, this simply won't be true (and that is no problem).

Comment: I was reading about QR decomposition. They claim that $||Q|| = 1$. I did an example and found a $Q$. Then I wanted to check $||Q|| = 1$, so I did $Q^T*Q$, which gives the identity since $Q$ is orthogonal ($Q^T*Q = Q^{-1}*Q = I_n$), and finally I did $||Q|| = \sqrt{tr(Q^T*Q)} = \sqrt{tr(Q^{-1}*Q)} = \sqrt{tr(I_n)}$ but when I calculated $tr(I_n)$ I got $2$ instead of $1$. I was expecting $1$.

Comment: Moreover, in Scilab, ||eye(2, 2)|| returns 1. norm(eye(2, 2)) = 1. trace(eye(2, 2)) returns 2.

Comment: @DavidRobertJones: It's been a while since I performed $QR$ decomposition, and so I couldn't instantly chip in if there is any contradiction in this regard. However, when you define the norm as you do (and which is one of several common possibilities), then your calculation is right. Are you familiar with [equivalence of norms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm)? Scilab probably uses a different norm.